# Phrase to tell, that you have written a fast note

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, titles

I am choosing a title for my essay, which is about a man, who wrote a fast idea on a napkin and lost in a pocket of his jacket. Then he dies in a car accident and ten years later his son finds an old jacket, finds a napkin and implements father's idea.

My candidate is a "Napkin note", but it seems too hackneyed. How to put in a phrase, that a man has written a fast note?

Comment: These kinds of ideas are usually described as having been written on *the back of a napkin*

Comment: @Jim Why not an answer? I wanna upvote it! I didn't know that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**"Jot Down a Note"** is a term that implies casual and fast without implying sloppiness.

Answer (score 1):

**Scribbled**?

> 1. write or draw (something) carelessly or hurriedly.

*.. his scribbled inheritance

  .. the scribbled note left by his father

  .. that the scribbled note lead to the atomic death robots was no surprise*

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> He [sketched out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sketch+out) a fast idea [on the back of an envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation).

And

> He [roughed out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rough+out) a fast idea on the back of an envelope.

Answer (score 1):

How do you feel about "Noted in Passing?"